# Get data from HTML page using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I would like to get the value 100 from the tag below using python and beautiful soup

```
<span style="font-size:90%"><b>100</b> <cite style="color:#cc0000"><b>-0.10</b> (0.52%)</cite></span>
```

The code below gives me the following output

```
100 -0.10 (0.52%)
```

How can I extract only the value 100?

Code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import bs4 
import re

url =  'url.com'
req = Request(url, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
page = urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find('span',style=re.compile('font-size:90%'))
value = data.text
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the first element of `soup.contents`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(page, 'html.parser').find('span', {'style':'font-size:90%'}).contents[0].text
```

Output:

```
'100'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just Find the `<b>` tag it will give you 100.

```
data = soup.find('span',style=re.compile('font-size:90%'))
value = data.find('b').text
```

Comment: oh! for some reason I missed this part from your original answer. Thank you for pointing it out